# Python list entries are overridden by last appended entry

Tags: python, list, append

I've got this code:

```
def __parse(self):        
    for line in self.lines:
        r = Record(line)
        self.records[len(self.records):] = [r]
        print self.records[len(self.records)-1].getValue() # Works fine!
    print self.record[0].getValue() # Gives the same as
    print self.record[1].getValue() # as
    # ... and so on ...
    print self.record[len(self.record)-1].getValue()
```

Now what it should do is making records out of lines of text. But when I access those list after the for-loop has completed all records give the same results for methods I call on them. When I access a record within the for-loop right after it was appended it's the right one so the Record **init** can't be fault. No, it's absolutely sure that the lines I put in are different! Has anyone an idea why this happens? Help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you just do self.records.append(r)?

Comment: Could you show us how `Record` is defined? If `Record` is storing `line` as a class attribute rather than a instance attribute, then that might explain the problem.

Comment: You only check the *latest* record in the loop. What about previous values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahue, you have mutable objects in the *shared* class namespace -- a very common misconception when starting out with python.  Move the initialization of `records = []` in `CsvSet` into its `__init__` function, and move `record = {}` into `Record` `__init__` function.  Should look like the following:

```
class Record:
    def __init__(self,lines):
        self.record = {}
        self.__parse()

class CsvSet:
    def __init__(self,lines):
        self.records = []
        self.__parse()
```

When you declare a mutable variable in the class area, it is shared among all instances of those classes, not created for each instance.   By moving the initialization into an instance method (`__init__` in this case), you are creating new mutable stores for each instance, which is what you intended.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought it was like in Java. Now it seems to work!

Answer (score 1):

You aren't appending to `self.records`; you are always overwriting it.

Use:

`self.records.append(r)`

instead.

**Edit**: Never mind.  See Ignacio Vasquez-Abrams's comment.  I would delete this answer if not for that.

Comment: Actually, `L[len(L):] = [X]` is a pathological form of append.

Comment: That is some pretty decent obfuscation.

Answer (score 1):

Does it still happen if you replace it with the following:

```
self.record = [Record(l) for l in self.lines]
```

**EDIT:**

Something *must* be wrong in `Record` since the code there does work, even if it makes experienced coders weep when they read it.

Comment: I also think it is the Record() class which is broken. I really wonder how it is implemented… Seeing the `self.records[len(self.records):] = [r]
` (valid!) code I guess it may be something 'clever' too :)

Similar problems (overwriting some 'other' data) happen in case of mutable vs. immutable structure confusion and e.g. when using lists as default arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Record class is broken. You use a class variable (Record.record) instead of an instance attribute. Class variable is one for all instances and you want different `self.record` for each instance.

Move the:

```
record = {}
line = ""
```

lines into the constructor (indented under `def __init__(self,line):`)

Answer (score 0):

The Record class is broken, you are always returning the same object.

Without seeing the code for Record it's impossible to guess

Perhaps you are using a list or a dict as default parameter to `__init__` and returning that with `getValue()`.

Another possibility is that `getValue()` is returning a class attribute rather than an instance attribute

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I'll post the code for the Record class for clarification, too.

> class Record:
>
> ```
> record = {}
> line = ""
>
> def __init__(self,line):
>     self.line = line 
>     self.__parse()
>
> def __parse(self):
>     fieldnames = ['from','to','value','error']
>     fields = self.line.split(',')
>
>     c = 0
>     for field in fields:
>         self.record[fieldnames[c]] = field.strip()
>         c+=1
>
>     self.record['from'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.record['from'],"%Y-%m-%d")
>     self.record['to'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.record['to'],"%Y-%m-%d")
> ```
>
> class CsvSet:
>
> ```
> records = []
>
> def __init__(self,lines):
>     self.__parse()
>
> def __parse(self):        
>     for line in self.lines:
>         self.records.append(Record(line))
> ```

The __parse method in CsvSet is now how it was in the beginning. I changed if for debugging reasons but the result is the same. And Ignacio you're right, I startet with Python only 2 weeks ago...

Comment: You should edit your original question instead of adding this as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do it next time. Sorry!